# Should there be a penalty for asking questions that get closed?

Tags: discussion, reputation, penalty

There seems to be a lot of off-topic questions coming at the minute (several re Oracle/Google ring a bell etc).

It often seems to me that people are asking off topic questions for maybe a bit of "rep-hunting", or perhaps just general stupidity.

Perhaps there should be something like a -10 rep penalty for asking a question that gets closed? Maybe people would hunt around for similar questions or not ask silly questions in the first place.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50358/what-is-with-people-who-answer-questions-that-are-known-to-be-dupes

Answer (score 7):

I'd rather see that users can't gain anything from having their questions closed.

Since people can still vote on closed questions, especially answering duplicates can still gain you some rep.

So rather than punishing users for their mistakes, I'd rather see users not gain from it

Comment: Exact dupe of my question (see comment under the question), which turned out to be a dupe of an earlier answer by @Ether.

Comment: @Popular Demand. Damn, I think we fell in an infinite loop...

Answer (score 1):

A bit harsh to the newcomers, but perhaps appropriate for the initiated (minimum rep of say 200? With provisions for keeping it thus. That is, if you get above 200 then fall below, the penalty still applies). Should not apply to migrated questions either.

Answer (score 1):

Opposed.

Many closed questions are asked in good faith.

I would support closed questions and their answers no automatically become CW though so no reputation is gained.

Comment: I am opposed to question being turned CW if closed. If question are incorrectly closed as duplicate, CW process can't be reversed while close process can be.

Comment: @HoLyVieR good point.

Answer (score 1):

I think perhaps more could be done to prevent duplication in the first place.

My favourite feature of SO, by far, is the "Related Questions" section just before you ask a question. It's smarter than the regular search for some reason, and could (should?) replace it.

Answer (score 1):

Closed questions can ultimately be [deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that-actually-mean), and they should if they are off-topic enough. This removes any Rep gained from it, but not right away. It requires a Rep recalc, which doesn't happen all that often under most circumstances.

That's why I suggest that Rep should be automatically recalculated whenever a user has a post deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Just came across [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3828/dis-incentive-to-ask-questions-that-will-get-closed) - couldn't find anything similar when I posted the Q. Sorry if I've come across as a bit of a troll.

Comment: No problem - but it illustrates an important point: It would not really be fair to give you a -10 penalty for not finding that duplicate, would it?

Comment: You're absolutely right. I'm really not sure. Just seems like theres quite a lot of noise at the minute.

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be. There is already reputation caps to make sure people don't get insane amount of reputation on subjective or bad question.

It's practically impossible to reach 2k reputation from asking question that eventually gets close. You would by that time be warned and suspended. Under 2k reputation your moderation power is pretty trivial, so I don't see any problem with people getting a bit of reputation from closed question.